# Jssor Getting the caurosel demo to display 3 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am trying to edit the carousel slider for Jssor to show three images instead of four.

I can't find where it's specified - can anyone help me?

http://www.jssor.com/demos/carousel-slider.html

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `$DisplayPieces: 4` with `$DisplayPieces: 3` to display 3 slides instead of 4.

And then replace `809px` with `606px` in html code to let the slider to fit size of 3 slides.